# Unable to rectify my script to skip the blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the second last portion of a big string (separated by space) using vba. My script is doing fine until it hits a blank cell. When any cell contains nothing then it breaks throwing an error `Subscript out of range`. How can I modify my script in such a way so that It will check first whether any cell is blank. If it finds any blank cell then it will skip that and look for the next cell until the last row?

This is what I've tried so far. It works smoothly until it encounters a blank cell.

```
Sub splitting_items()
    Dim lrow As Long, cel As Range
    Dim i As Long, item_list As Variant

    lrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & lrow)
        item_list = Split(cel, " ")
        i = UBound(item_list)
        Debug.Print item_list(i - 1)
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Applied on the below strings. The leading numbers are the row number with 3 and 4 blank.

```
1 BEBEE TABERNACLE CHURCH CME
2 OCHOA VICTORIANO RLT
3
4
5 MIDCON TEXAS PIPELINE CORP
6 STD DALLAS ST STE
```

Comment: Wrap your processing of each cel within an `If Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then` block?  Or use an `If i <> LBound(item_list) Then` around the `Debug.Print` statement?

Comment: Actually, just checking for `IsEmpty` won't work, because your code will also break for any cell that has a value but no embedded space, e.g. a cell value of `"ABCD"` will break it.

Comment: Yep, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try testing the value:

```
Sub splitting_items()
    Dim lrow As Long, cel As Range
    Dim i As Long, item_list As Variant

    lrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & lrow)
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, " ") <> 0 Then
            item_list = Split(cel, " ")
            i = UBound(item_list)
            Debug.Print item_list(i - 1)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution never fails @Gary's Student. You are the wizard of vba. Thanksssss a trillion.

Comment: @Topto  Thank you for the feedback................in this case the concept *(test before you fail)* is more important then the actual code.

Comment: If I'm not expecting much then a little question on this topic: when I execute the script, it does it's job flawlessly but when It comes to place those scraped values in it's appropriate position (i meant next to the concerning string) it fails. To be specific: if Range("B2") is blank and I'm parsing the value of Range("C2") then the scraped portion is getting settled in Range("B3") whereas the right position is Range("C3"). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a workaround. If I try like below, It can handle blank rows and always places the parsed values in it's appropriate position, I meant next to the appropriate strings.

```
Sub splitting_items()
    Dim cel As Range, i As Long, item_list As Variant

    For Each cel In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        item_list = Split(cel, " ")
        i = UBound(item_list)
        cel(1, 2) = item_list(i - 1)
    Next cel
End Sub
```